# Print lines from readline() without double spacing

Tags: readline

I'm trying to print the top 10 lines of a file. single spaced. without spaces at the end
What can i change so that the output is single spaced instead of double spaced?
thanks

so far I've got:

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
i = 1
while i <= 10:
    line = f.readline()
    print line
    i = i+1
f.close()
```

and i get an out put of:

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Answer (score 1):

easiest fix is to put a comma on the end of the print statement:

change

```
print line
```

to

```
print line,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`str.rstrip('\n')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to do this. `rstrip` trims a trailing character, which in this case would be `\n` (newline character).

```
with open('1.txt') as f:
    i = 1
    while i <= 10:
        line = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
        print line
        i = i+1
    f.close()
```